# Can someone provide an example for the ImageCompare methods?

Tags: c#, .net, class, types, static

I'm attempting to compare two images using Visual Studio 2013 Pro. The MSDN provides information (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.imagecomparer.compare.aspx) on ImageComparer.Compare, alas I'm failing to get it implemented in my code. On the last line of my code I'm told that "The name 'Compare' does not exist in the current context". Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;


namespace Intranet.SmokeTests
{
public class Intranet_Login : Intranet_Setup
{
    public List<string> IntranetLoginTest(string BrowserURL, string Host, int Port)
    {
            Image expected = Image.FromFile(@"\\webdriver\ImageVerification\Expected\IntranetHome.png");
            Image actual = Image.FromFile(@"\\webdriver\ImageVerification\Actual\IntranetHome.png");

            bool equal = Compare(actual, expected);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the correct version of the referenced dll was not being added. The complete answer is here: [How can I make the namespace locally match what is listed on MSDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021118/how-can-i-make-the-namespace-locally-match-what-is-listed-on-msdn)

Answer (score 3):

You must do it like this:

```
bool equal = ImageComparer.Compare(actual, expected);
```

When you want to use a class's static member in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) you must always qualify it with the class first. Otherwise the compiler will try to locate the member on the current class.

Another problem you might be having with your `IntranetLoginTest` is that it's supposed to return an instance of `List<string>`, but it doesn't. I must also say I find it strange that you are making an image comparison test in a method that would suggest it performs authentication mechanisms testing.

Comment: When I try that, I get the same error. I suspect that I'm missing a reference or something 'minor'. But I've already added the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting reference to the project.

Comment: You can't possibly be having the *exact* same error. In this case if you missed a reference then the message would be that `ImageComparer` cannot be found. In any case, make sure your test project has a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting. If it does and that your `Using` statements on top of your file are the same as in your example, this should compile just fine. Otherwise you're having another problem, elsewhere.

Comment: In that case it seems like my problem is elsewhere... Thanks for confirming my thoughts.

Comment: @WarioX You are welcome but still I'm very curious what your problem could be. :) If you can share whatever new information / error message you have using my solution I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

1- Using nuget Install `System.Drawing.Common`

2- Reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll` from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform

```
        Image expected = Image.FromFile(@"2020-09-01_15h31_24.png");
        Image actual = Image.FromFile(@"2020-09-01_15h31_30.png");
        Image difference = null;

        var isTestPass = ImageComparer.Compare(actual, expected, out difference);

        if (!isTestPass)
            difference.Save("diff.png");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Expected
[image]

Actual
[image]

Difference
[image]