# How can I make the namespace locally match what is listed on MSDN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Premium. When I consult MSDN, it lists the classes available for the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting namespace. However when I view that namespace through the Object Browser, it doesn't list all of the classes. This is further evidenced when I try to use the ImageComparer class. How can I get all of the classes?

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.aspx

Local Object Browser:

[image: Object Browser Screenshot]

Comment: Have you ensured that you've added a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll`?  Not through a `using` but an actual reference.

Comment: @Greg I have the reference added, cleaned solution, rebuilt (multiple times), and still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you've referenced a different Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll . This can happen if you've had multiple versions of VS installed. Did you browse to the location for this or did you add it from Assemblies? Both can make quite the difference.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had to browse to the location and add it that way. It works now. Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies